# oracle sql developer sdcli utility import error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run some imports from an excel file using de sdcli utility import command, but I get an error. When I import from the sql developer gui the import works fine.

This is the command I run:

`sdcli utility import -config import_file.sdimp`

This is the command output:

````
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.data.readers.DataReaderRegistry.getReader(DataReaderRegistry.java:45)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.data.core.ImportXMLUtil.reconcileConfig(ImportXMLUtil.java:1378)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.data.core.ImportXMLUtil.reconcileConfig(ImportXMLUtil.java:1076)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.data.core.ImportXMLUtil.reconcileConfig(ImportXMLUtil.java:1068)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.data.headless.ImportCommand.doCommand(ImportCommand.java:177)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.data.headless.ImportProcessor$ImportHeadlessTask.doWork(ImportProcessor.java:37)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.data.headless.ImportProcessor$ImportHeadlessTask.doWork(ImportProcessor.java:27)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sdcli.exe utility import -c C:\temp\isd.sdimp -conn prod_db
```

C:\temp\isd.sdimp file is created by SQL developer, XML can be manipulated, and connection must be given from the command line, so you can create a script to import data into a table, which you do not "see" as you do missing rights in "prod_db" and DBA is "untouchable"[image]